# remote svn up won't finish

Tags: svn, ssh

I ssh to the remote application server where I need to do svn up. That is one amongst few servers. Should have the same set up as all other ones where svn up works.

- ssh to the server
- su wwwrun finishes ok
- `svn info` gives me

`URL: svn+ssh://svnuser@repository.server.com.au/var/lib/svn/edu2/tags/4.1.0`

- `svn st` runs ok too.
- ssh svnuser@repository.server.com.au logs me in without asking for password.
- `svn up` will never finish

If I log into repository server using another session and do `ps aux |grep svn` I can see that  process `svnserve -t` under svnuser is running. If I do `ctrl+c` in the session where I started svn up I get `^Csvn: Caught signal` and the process `svnserve -t` on repository server will finish.

When I try `svn up` on few other application servers that (should) have the same set up everything works fine. The ssh to the server in question is slow but svn up worked on even slower connections.

Any idea how to fix that or debug what is going on?

Comment: Does `svn st` show any locked (L) or switched (S) files? `svn st` does not connect to server unless `-u` is used. A `svn cleanup` might also help. Monitor svn log file as well.

Comment: What helped was fresh checkout of the codebase. Nothing above helped.